Time frame for user activity history displaying in Banno People
How far back is a user's activity displayed in Banno people? It looks like I can only pull up two years of activity for a user.
I have tested with a few banks and CUs that have been live on Banno for more than two years. I was able to only pull up two years to the month of a user's activity in Banno People. It was under the impression that it was indefinitely.
